# Does visiting the localhost with my Tor browser reduce my security?

Tags: webserver, tor

I happen to have Tor open right now, and want to do a quick modification to my website.

Does visiting `localhost` with Tor reduce the security of that session?

Comment: Of which session? Are you asking if a browser session to `localhost` would go through onion routers? Or if there was a threat of leaking the info through another open sessions?

Comment: Doubtful it went through Tor at all. If you visit localhost the computer knows to route directly to itself and not externally unless the DNS entry is configured differently.

Comment: @techraf I know very little about Tor in general, and just wondered if visiting would reveal my details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably wouldn't work. If you told the Tor exit relay, "I want to go to `127.0.0.1`" (that's the IP of `localhost`), it would try to connect to itself, because that's what that IP means. Unless the exit relay had a web server running, the connection would fail. I wouldn't be surprised if the Tor software checks for loopback IPs and rejects the connection.

It's entirely possible that Tor will just connect you directly to yourself. If that happens, there's no harm done because no traffic leaves your machine. (Unless you're running a malicious deanonymizing site on your computer that sends your IP to shady people.)

If `localhost` is somehow magically changed into your external IP before being sent through Tor, you're still fine. Unless you've made a firewall rule, configured your web server, and set up portforwarding from your external IP to your computer, the connection will fail. If it did go through, no node on the way would have any idea that you just talked to yourself, since only the entry guard knows the source and only the exit node knows the destination.

Comment: So even visiting my own domain is safe - and makes no difference to my privacy?

Comment: That's right. No node along the way will be able to tell for sure that it's the same person. Again, I'm making the fairly safe assumption that your own site isn't going to hand over all your information to bad guys. But even if it did, Tor does a pretty good job of making all Tor users look very similar.